# Python apply_async doesn't modify numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, classification, shared-memory, multiprocess

I am trying to perform a classification task on a large numpy Array. For context the Array is a conversion of a satellite image.
The goal is to classify each pixel with its surrounding neighbours. I am therefore using a CNN on a 50x50 patch. As the task is very slow with a double loop sliding window I tried using multiprocessing pool. The result of each predict is stored in a numpy called "classif" that contains the class of each pixel.
I know that the code works because of the multiple prints but it doesn't seem to modify the array "classif". Indeed the output is always an array full of zeros.

I think I am not really modifying "classif" but just a copy of it but I can't seem to acess it with the methods I found online.

Can someone help me on that issue ?

X_test is my large Array

```
patch_width = 50               
patch_height = patch_width
pad= 25
NUM_PROCESSES=4



img_height, img_width, band = X_test.shape


N = X_test.shape[0]
P = (NUM_PROCESSES + 1) 
partitions = list(zip(np.linspace(0, N, P, dtype=int)[:-1], np.linspace(0, N, P, dtype=int)[1:]))
work = partitions[:-1]
work.append((partitions[-1][0], partitions[-1][1]))


M = X_test.shape[1]
partitions2 = list(zip(np.linspace(0, M, P, dtype=int)[:-1],
    np.linspace(0, M, P, dtype=int)[1:]))

# Final range of indices should end +1 past last index for completeness
work2 = partitions2[:-1]
work2.append((partitions2[-1][0], partitions2[-1][1] ))


work3=list()
for i in work:
    for j in work2:
        n= list((j,i))
        work3.append(n)



X_class = np.pad(X_test, ((pad,pad), (pad,pad), (0, 0)), 'reflect')
        
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=X_class.nbytes)
X_class_shared = np.ndarray(X_class.shape, dtype=X_class.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
X_class_shared =X_class.copy()

classif_shape = np.zeros((img_height, img_width), dtype=int)

shm2 = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=classif_shape.nbytes)
classif = np.ndarray(classif_shape.shape, dtype=classif_shape.dtype, buffer=shm2.buf)


def predict(height, width):
    for i in range(width[0],width[1]):
        for j in range(height[0],height[1]):
            x=j 
            x_bis = j+patch_height
            y=i
            y_bis=i +patch_width 
            patch = X_class_shared[x:x_bis,y:y_bis, :]
            X = np.expand_dims(patch, axis=0)
            test = cnn.predict(X)
            rounded = np.argmax(test, axis=1)
            classif[j,i]=rounded



def dispatch_jobs(data, job_number):

    pool =Pool(job_number)
    for i, s in work3:
        pool.apply_async(predict, args=(s,i))
    print(classif)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    dispatch_jobs(work3,NUM_PROCESSES)
```